# ng-switch in Angular with Parent Child Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have following HTML

```
<html ng-app="app" ng-csp="">
    <body ng-controller="MainController" capture ng-class="view">
     <div id="wrap" ng-switch="view">
          <div id="login" ng-switch-when="login" ng-controller="SignInController">
           my login code  
         </div>
          <div id="project" ng-switch-when="project" ng-controller="ProjectController">
           my login code  
         </div>

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my Angular code is

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", function(t) {
/* check session  if exist or not if not show login*/  
    t.view='login';
}]),app.controller("SignInController", ["$scope","$http", function(t,$http) {
t.signIn = function() {
    $http({
            url: "/login/",
            data: { email: t.user.email,password:t.user.password },
            method: 'POST',
        }).success(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                //want to show project div
                t.$emit("view", "project");

        }).error(function(err){  
             t.error = "Invalid Login";
        })
};


}]),app.controller("ProjectController", ["$scope", function(t) {



}]);
```

Now my ng-swicth is not wokring on Success.
**EDIT :**
here is punker link http://plnkr.co/edit/I8EEFM8gdplUmNaZoYc6

when i click on login button, i want to show project switch.

Any Suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that $scope is not shared between your controllers. Start by only having one Controller, so $scope is shared as you expect.

Changing your ExampleController to this:

```
var app = angular.module("switchExample", []); 
app.controller("ExampleController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.selection ="settings";
  $scope.signIn = function() {
    alert("click");
     $scope.selection ="project";
  }
}]);
```

... and deleting the other Controller and the references to the unused Controllers in the HTML will display 'hello' when you click 'Login'

Comment: that is working. if i need to use multiple controller, then how i can use ?

Comment: One may use $rootScope to bind variables that need to be shared between Controllers, as the $scope variable of a Controller inherits from the $rootScope. Reads the docs on $rootScope

Answer (score 2):

I think you got it wrong. The syntax for [ng-switch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) is:

`<ANY ng-switch="expression">
  <ANY ng-switch-when="matchValue1">...</ANY>
  <ANY ng-switch-when="matchValue2">...</ANY>
  <ANY ng-switch-default>...</ANY>
</ANY>`

It consumes a variable (member of $scope) and has nothing to do with events.

Instead of `t.$emit("view", "project");` you should do `$scope.view = "project";`.

Please see the example at the bottom of the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

Comment: Please, learn the example at documentation page. It's quite straightforward

Comment: I am passing t 
instead of $scope
app.controller("SignInController", ["$scope","$http", function(t,$http)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<div id="wrap" ng-switch on="view">
```

And setting:

```
$scope.view = "project";
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'not working'? Are there any errors? Which version of AngularJS are you using?

Comment: when i click on login project switch is not showing

Comment: It seems to me you expect the $scope in the SignInController and in the ProjectController to be the same. AFAIK, they are not. Perhaps, you could bind your variable 'settings' to $rootScope instead, as this will be inherited by the two controller scopes

Comment: Could you please provide example for that.

Comment: ... or you could move signIn() to the ExampleController so you are operating on the same $scope

Comment: I have added another answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<html ng-app="app" ng-csp="">
<body ng-controller="MainController" capture ng-class="view">
 <div id="wrap" ng-switch on="view">
      <div id="login" ng-switch-when="'login'" ng-controller="SignInController">
       my login code  
     </div>
      <div id="project" ng-switch-when="'project'" ng-controller="ProjectController">
       my login code  
     </div>

</div>
</body>
```

use this html